# Sequential file initialization unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I'm trying to initialize a file with 100 empty records with the code below:

```
void initializeInventory() {
    std::ofstream out("hardware.dat", std::ios::binary);

    Hardware h;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        h.ID = i;
        h.name = "try"; // std::string();
        h.quantity = 0;
        h.price = 0;
        h.notes = "try2"; //std::string();

        out.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&h), sizeof(Hardware));
    }

    out.close();
}
```

But when I try to print them out, it always print only 25 elements or crashes.
This is the function to print out elements:

```
void readInventory() {
    std::ifstream in("hardware.dat", std::ios::in);
    std::cout << std::setiosflags(std::ios::left) << std::setw(4) << "ID"
              << std::setw(16) << "Name"
              << std::setw(11) << "Quantity"
              << std::setw(10) << std::resetiosflags(std::ios::left)
              << "Price"
              << std::setw(50) << "Notes" << '\n';

    Hardware h;

    while (!in.eof()) {
        in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&h), sizeof(Hardware));

        //if (!in.eof())
            printOut(std::cout, h);
    }

    in.close();
}

void printOut(std::ostream &output, const Hardware& h) {
    output << std::setiosflags(std::ios::left) << std::setw(4) << h.ID
           << std::setw(16) << h.name
           << std::setw(11) << h.quantity
           << std::setw(10) << std::setprecision(2)
           << std::resetiosflags(std::ios::left)
           << std::setiosflags(std::ios::fixed | std::ios::showpoint )
           << h.price
           << std::setw(50) << h.notes << '\n';
}
```

I also noted that if I increase the number of cycles in the for (I tried putting 400 instead of 100) the file *hardware.dat* seems to grow, so I thought that should be a problem in the print function. Any idea? Is there something I'm missing?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be the best to overload the operator <<

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Hardware& h) // output
{
    out << "(" << h.id() << ", " << h.whatever() << ")";
    return out;
}
```

and read the file line by line to the Hardware object. 
By the way, overloading the input operator >> is also possible.